# Data retrieval from MongoDB does not work when I change my routing

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new with Express, MongoDB and Angular and I am trying to make a website with multiple html files. I've managed to get the index page working so when it refreshes, it loads up nicely but when I refresh on another page for example localhost:3000/examplepage, it says the page does not exist.

In Express I render the index file like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.render('index'); // 
});
```

My getdata post is MongoDB:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/loodgieters');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userDataSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  adress: String,
  postal: String,
  city: String,
  email: String,
  phone: String,
  quotation: String,
  message: String
}, {collection: 'userdata'});

var UserData = mongoose.model('UserData', userDataSchema);

router.get('/getdata', function(req, res, next){
  UserData.find()
  .then(function(doc){
    console.log('Data successfully retrieved');
    res.render('index', {items: doc});
   });
});
```

When I change "/" to "*", it renders all files and it works fine, but then my mongoDB "getdata" does not work anymore. So it won't retrieve any data from my database anymore. How can I get this to work?

Comment: share your complete code (handler, query etc) for us to help you.

Comment: Why are you writing your `/getdata` route in mongodb file? where is your route for `localhost:3000/examplepage`? How are you calling your `getdata` from your route?